# "failed writing body & data" libcurl c++

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

Hi I'm trying to save CURL server response and getting following error:
I read that is due to difference in size between data read and written to a file so curl is crushing. File is created and contains need XML data but still shows error. THANK you for your help!!

- Failed writing body (0 != 96)
- Failed writing data
- Closing connection #0

here are my cb function:

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{  size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream); return written; }
```

and method:

createJob(std::string s, std::string directory) {

```
    static const char *fp = "resultcurl.xml";
    std::stringstream filepath;
filepath<< directory;
    filepath<< fp;

    std::string pagefilename = filepath.str();

FILE *pagefile;
    std::string job_id;

struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;

std::string jobXML = s;
curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl) {

    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: */*");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/xml");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,
            ".../jobs.xml");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "...");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, jobXML.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, strlen(jobXML.c_str()));

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,write_data);

            pagefile = fopen(pagefilename.c_str(), "wb");

       if (pagefile) {


            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, pagefile);

            //curl_easy_perform(curl);


          }

          res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

            /* cleanup curl stuff */ 
          curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

           //job_id =readXMLvalue(pagefilename);
          fclose(pagefile);
          return 0;

}
```

Comment: same error also with CURLOPT_WRITEDATA

Comment: sorry i forgot to proved all method. It has path to file, and file contains data :o is not empty. This is what confuse me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the order of the setup,

```
   pagefile = fopen(pagefilename.c_str(), "wb");
   if (pagefile) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, pagefile);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,write_data);
        ...
   }
   ...
```

Comment: tnx it works if I put writefunction inside of if part

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write data into the file, Curl will do it for you. set

```
if(curl_easy_setopt( curl , CURLOPT_WRITEDATA , (void *) fptr  ) != CURLE_OK)
{
    return(YOUR_ERR_CODE) ;
}
```

where fptr is,

```
FILE *fptr = fopen( "emalware.127.5a6ceb78050f80e4c833dcc3764bf9dd.gzip", "wb" );
if( fptr == NULL )
{
   return -1;
}
```